# ggplot not properly displaying

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, cumsum

I currently am trying to graph 2 columns in a data frame I created using ggplot

I am graphing date vs. numeric value. I used dplyr library to create the dataframe:

```
is_china <- confirmed_cases_worldwide %>%
  filter(country == "China", type=='confirmed') %>%
  mutate(cumu_cases = cumsum(cases))
```

I believe the reason is due to the y value being a result column of cumsum function, but am unsure

The table looks something like this, the last column being the targeted y value:

```
    2020-01-22  NA  China   31.8257 117.2264    confirmed   1   1
2   2020-01-23  NA  China   31.8257 117.2264    confirmed   8   9
3   2020-01-24  NA  China   31.8257 117.2264    confirmed   6   15
4   2020-01-25  NA  China   31.8257 117.2264    confirmed   24  39
5   2020-01-26  NA  China   31.8257 117.2264    confirmed   21  60
6   2020-01-27  NA  China   31.8257 117.2264    confirmed   10  70
7   2020-01-28  NA  China   31.8257 117.2264    confirmed   36  106
8   2020-01-29  NA  China   31.8257 117.2264    confirmed   46  152
```

When I graph this with the column cases(second to last on the table), it is fine, but when I try graphing with the cumulative cases, the graph is very volitle:

[image]

I am unsure why.

Comment: I assume You use `geom_line()` for plotting, so I suggest You look at `group` argument for `aes`. E.g (hard to give an example not seeing a full working example) - `ggplot(is_china, aes(x = date_col, y = cumu_cases, group = country) + geom_line()`

Comment: @Linards Kalvans Yes, sorry i didn't include my executed line, ```ggplot(data= is_china, aes(x=date,y=cumu_cases)) + geom_line() ``` and also I only have China in my country category so I didn't think i needed ```group= county ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(is_china,aes(x = as.Date(date),y = cumu_cases)) +
   geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: My code is ```ggplot(data= is_china, aes(x=date,y=cumu_cases)) + geom_line() ``` and my date column is already as a date type while y is a numeric type

Comment: @king_sules If you can provide a link to your data, I can try to help more.

Comment: https://github.com/king-sules/Covid Im essentially trying to execute this code ```ggplot(china_vs_world) +
  geom_line(aes(x=date,y=cumu_cases,group=country,color=country)) +
  ylab("Cumulative confirmed cases") ``` To show 2 different lines in same graph

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to group by country, but there is just one country.

```
library(dplyr)
is_china <- confirmed_cases_worldwide %>%
  filter(country == "China", type=='confirmed') %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))

unique(is_china$country)
# [1] "China"
```

However, the `lat` and `long` variables with 33 distinctions indicate that we have panel data. So without considering the panel structure, you get strange values with `cumsum`; besides, the variable is already there and we don't need to calculate it again. Altogether this explains the strange lines you're getting.

Since the `province` variable is empty, we could use `lat` and `long` to generate a new `gps` variable for grouping.

```
unique(is_china$lat)
# [1] 31.8257 40.1824 30.0572 26.0789 ...  [33] 29.1832
unique(is_china$long)
# [1] 117.2264 116.4142 107.8740 117.9874 ... [33] 120.0934

is_china$gps <- apply(is_china[4:5], 1, function(x) Reduce(paste, x))
```

Now we can plot the data using `gps` as a `factor`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(is_china, aes(x=date, y=cumu_cases, color=factor(gps))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

To select only specific coordinates you may subset your data, e.g.:

```
ggplot(is_china[is_china$gps %in% c("30.9756 112.2707", "22.3 114.2"), ],
       aes(x=date, y=cumu_cases, color=factor(gps))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
confirmed_cases_worldwide <- 
  read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/king-sules/Covid/master/china_vs_world.csv")
```

Comment: I actually have 2 countries, one is 'china' and other is 'not china' I even made a distinct table to only include the cumsum values but to no avail

Comment: Why are you opening two questions on the same topic? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61993479/6574038