# Plotting in ggplot using cumsum

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, cumsum

I am trying to use ggplot2 to plot a date column vs. a numeric column.

I have a dataframe that I am trying to manipulate with country as either china or not china, and successfully created the dataframe linked below with:

```
is_china <- confirmed_cases_worldwide %>%
  filter(country == "China", type=='confirmed') %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(cumu_cases = cumsum(cases)) 

is_not_china <- confirmed_cases_worldwide %>%
  filter(country != "China", type=='confirmed') %>%
  mutate(cumu_cases = cumsum(cases))

is_not_china$country <- "Not China"

china_vs_world <- rbind(is_china,is_not_china)
```

Now essentially I am trying to plot a line graph with `cumu_cases` and `date` between "china" and "not china" 
I am trying to execute this code:

```
plt_china_vs_world <- ggplot(china_vs_world) +
  geom_line(aes(x=date,y=cumu_cases,group=country,color=country)) +
  ylab("Cumulative confirmed cases")
```

Now I keep getting a graph looking like this: [image]

Don't understand why this is happening, been trying to convert data types and other methods. 
Any help is appreciated, I linked both csv below

https://github.com/king-sules/Covid

Comment: It would help to see the code which generates `confirmed_cases_worldwide `. Presumably you have read and filtered `coronavirus.csv` somehow?

Comment: Your code for the `cumu_cases` looks right so it might be something with the date. It would help if you post an example dataset that reproduces the problem

Comment: The issue is that you have dates for all the other countries and it is repeated because the country is now changed to 'Not China'.  In the second case, you may need to group_by. 'date' `confirmed_cases_worldwide %>%
  filter(country != "China", type=='confirmed')  %>% group_by(date) %>%  summarise(cumu_cases = sum(cases)) %>% mutate(cumu_cases = cumsum(cumu_cases))`

Comment: @neilfws yup, ```confirmed_cases_worldwide``` is the same as ```coronovirus.csv```

Comment: Why are you opening two questions on the same topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61979426/ggplot-not-properly-displaying

Comment: If any answer helps don't forget to close the question by accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'date' for other 'country' are repeated because the 'country' is now changed to 'Not China'.  It would be either changed in the OP's 'is_not_china' step or do this in 'china_vs_world'

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
china_vs_world %>%
   group_by(country, date) %>%
   summarise(cumu_cases = sum(cases)) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   mutate(cumu_cases = cumsum(cumu_cases)) %>%
   ggplot() +  
    geom_line(aes(x=date,y=cumu_cases,group=country,color=country)) + 
       ylab("Cumulative confirmed cases")
```

-output

[image]

NOTE: It is the scale that shows the China numbers to be small.

As @Edward mentioned a log scale would make it more easier to understand

```
china_vs_world %>%
   group_by(country, date) %>%
   summarise(cumu_cases = sum(cases)) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   mutate(cumu_cases = cumsum(cumu_cases)) %>%
   ggplot() +  
    geom_line(aes(x=date,y=cumu_cases,group=country,color=country)) + 
       ylab("Cumulative confirmed cases") +     
    scale_y_continuous(trans='log')
```

[image]

Or with a `facet_wrap`

```
china_vs_world %>% 
   group_by(country, date) %>%
   summarise(cumu_cases = sum(cases)) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   mutate(cumu_cases = cumsum(cumu_cases)) %>%      
  ggplot() +  
    geom_line(aes(x=date,y=cumu_cases,group=country,color=country)) + 
      ylab("Cumulative confirmed cases") +
    facet_wrap(~ country, scales = 'free_y')
```

[image]

#### data

```
china_vs_world <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/king-sules/Covid/master/china_vs_world.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
china_vs_world$date <- as.Date(china_vs_world$date)
```

Comment: Do you need the last mutate? The data are already cumulative sums.

Comment: @Edward the `sum` of 'cases' is doing the sum by 'date', but I guess the OP' needed the `cumsum`

Comment: @Edward I am not using the 'cumu_cases' column created in the OP's data because it is not correct

Comment: How about a log scale for y-axis? It looks interesting.